# Integración de CRM Dynamics y telefonía (conmutador)

Tags: dynamics-crm

quiero integrar nuestra telefonía con el módulo de Call Center CRM, donde permita realizar las siguientes acciones:

1. Presentar de manera automática la ficha del cliente una vez que entre la llamada.
2. En caso de que el número telefónico sea desconocido, de manera automática se presente en el CRM la sección de prospecto o una oportunidad.
3. Identificar el número de llamadas que realizan nuestros clientes por periodos.
4. Identificación de los número telefónicos desconocidos que no fueron atendidos por nuestros operadores.

Existen herramientas como "PowerPhone", que realiza algunas funciones anteriormente mencionadas. Sin embargo, desconozco si en la producción realmente funciona este tipo de herramientas y en especial si son compatibles con nuestro conmutador (NEC SL 1000) o requiero que hacer un cambio en nuestros equipos.  Espero que me puedan orientar,  indicándome cual herramienta les ha sido de gran utilidad como intermediario entre su CRM y conmutador. Así mismo, indicarme que requerimientos debo considerar para realizar dicha implementación.